# RubyNoMethodError - call a ruby method from Java

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

I have this ruby class :

```
require 'stringio'
require 'hirb'

class Engine
  def initialize()
    @binding = Kernel.binding
  end
  def run(code)
    # run something
    stdout_id = $stdout.to_i
    $stdout = StringIO.new
    cmd = <<-EOF
    $SAFE = 3
    $stdout = StringIO.new
    begin
      #{code}
    end
    EOF
    begin
      result = Thread.new { Kernel.eval(cmd, @binding) }.value
    rescue SecurityError
      return "illegal"
    rescue Exception => e
      return e
    ensure
      output = get_stdout
      $stdout = IO.new(stdout_id)
    end

    return output
  end

   private
   def get_stdout
     raise TypeError, "$stdout is a #{$stdout.class}" unless $stdout.is_a? StringIO
     $stdout.rewind
     $stdout.read
   end
end
```

The "run" method should call an IRB's function and to capture the output (string format).
I want to call this function from a Java class but it can't find the IRB methods, even they are loaded (require 'hirb').
My java class looks like this :

```
public class MyClass {
  private final static String jrubyhome = "/usr/lib/jruby/";
  private String rubySources;
  private String hirbSource;
  private String myEngine;
  private boolean loaded = false;

  private void loadPaths() {
    String userDir;

    userDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    rubySources = userDir + "/../ruby";
    hirbSource = userDir + "/hirb.rb";
    myEngine = rubySources + "/engine.rb";

    System.setProperty("jruby.home", jrubyhome);
    System.setProperty("org.jruby.embed.class.path", rubySources+":"+hirbSource);
    System.setProperty("hbase.ruby.sources", rubySources+":"+hirbSource);
  }

  private String commandResponse(String command) 
     throws FileNotFoundException
  { 
    String response;

    loadPaths();

    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("jruby");
    ScriptingContainer container = new ScriptingContainer();

    Reader reader = new FileReader(myEngine);

    try {
      Object receiver = engine.eval(reader);
      String method = "run";
      Object ob  = container.callMethod(receiver,method,command);
      response = ob.getClass().toString();

      return response;
    } catch (ScriptException e) {
      System.out.println("exception");
    } 

    return "FAILED";
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) 
    throws IOException {
     MyClass my = new MyClass();
     System.out.println(my.commandResponse(args[0]));
  }  
}
```

Do you know what could be the problem?

[EDITED] **After I extended the Kernel module and added the commands it worked.**

Comment: One possible source for NoMethodError is syntax difference. You might be trying to invoke a method with different parameters than required. Make sure version of Ruby and method invocation you are doing are in synch

Comment: if I invoke a method with wrong parameters the IRB should return a message with the correct call form and the run method should capture it